# How to Compare sysdate time and String time in Java

Tags: java, methods, time, simpledateformat, sysdate

What I want to do is:

- if the time is 10:00:00 proc.process will be executed
- if the time is 11:00:00 proc.process1 will be executed

---

```
String TimeVal = "11:00:00";
String TimeVal1 = "12:00:00";

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = sdf.parse(TimeVal);
Date date2 = sdf2.parse(TimeVal1);

if (date1 == date) {
    proc.process(variable);    
}
if (date1 == date) {
    proc.process1(variable);     

    proc.process2(variable);
    proc.process3(variable);
    proc.process4(variable);
    proc.process5(variable);
    proc.process6(variable);
    proc.process7(variable);
    proc.process8(variable);
    proc.process9(variable);
    proc.process10(variable);
    proc.process11(variable);
```

Comment: Why you don't use java 8 way ?

Comment: The very first thing to understand: == tells you if two **references** are pointing at the **same** object. When you parse two strings, you get **two** date objects; so your check will **always** be false. You have to use **equals()** instead. And seriously: if you are failing on such super basics, then you should step back and forget what you try to do right now. Because then you have almost no clue of nothing; and you better spent some weeks learning those **basics**. Otherwise, you will just run from one frustrating moment into the next one. Because **nothing** you try will work.

Comment: Do you any recommendation what basic do i need to study GhostCat

Comment: OCA Java Book study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
Boolean isNowWithinRange =
    ( 
        ( ! now.isBefore( LocalTime.parse( "11:00:00" ) ) ) 
        && now.isBefore( LocalTime.parse( "12:00:00" ) 
    ) ;
```

## Details

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612707/642706) is a good attempt but has multiple flaws.

Bad practice to call `now` twice, as you end up making invalid comparisons with two different moments. Call once, and assign to a variable.

Do not ignore the crucial issue of time zone. Better to explicitly pass the optional time zone argument to `now( ZoneId )` than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default which can change at any moment.

You can ask for the device’s current default time zone. But if vital, you should ask/confirm with the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); 
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z );
```

You can parse the input strings directly as `LocalTime` objects.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "11:00:00" );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "12:00:00" );
```

Common practice in date-time work is to use the Half-Open approach for spans of time. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Using this approach consistently makes your code more understandable and less error-prone.

Tip: Saying “not before start” is a briefer way of saying “is equal to or later than start”.

```
Boolean isNowWithinRange = ( ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && now.isBefore( stop ) ) ;
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the java 8 date api ?

Like :

```
 LocalTime firstTime = LocalTime.of(11, 0, 0); 
 LocalTime secondTime = LocalTime.of(12, 0, 0);
 LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

 if (now.isAfter(startTime) &&
     now.isBefore(endTime)){
     //process
 }
```

Comment: corrected, i couldnt check as i dont have java 8 on my current computer

Comment: For Half-Open approach where beginning is inclusive while ending is exclusive, that comparison would be: `( ! now.isBefore( startTime ) ) &&      now.isBefore( endTime )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your Date() objects, you could compare the millis:

```
if(date1.getTime() == date.getTime()) { 
// ...
}
```